# AngularJS - GET request in service sometimes does not actually hit server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browser

I have an angular factory service with a function `getLoggedInUser` which makes a GET request to my Node.js server.

When loading the page initially, it works fine (when `getLoggedInUser` is called by a controller, the method runs and a GET request at the path `/loggedInUser` is logged in the server logs).

But when I click `back` and then `forward` buttons in my browser (Firefox), the service method does indeed run (I `console.log` in it) but no such GET request appears in the server logs.

The `console.log` of the `$http.get` in `getLoggedInUser` somehow shows a result, even though no GET request hit the server.

Why is this happening when using `back` and `forward`? When using those buttons, does the browser not remake any http requests and just uses cached results? If so, how can I disable this cache behavior for the `$http.get` in `getLoggedInUser`? (I already tried `{cache: false}` as the second argument to `$http.get` and it didn't seem to work).

In the Angular.js client, service:

```
// services/auth.js

angular.module('authService', [])

    .factory('Auth', ['$http', function($http) {

        return {
            register: function(username, password) {
                return $http.post('/register', {username: username, password: password});
            },
            login: function(username, password) {
                return $http.post('/login', {username: username, password: password});
            },
            logout: function() {
                return $http.get('/logout');
            },
            getLoggedInUser: function() {
                var resp = $http.get('/loggedInUser');
                console.log(resp);
                return resp;
            }
        };

}]);
```

In the Angular.js client, controller:

```
// controllers/main.js

angular.module('braidController', [])

    .controller('mainController', ['Auth', function(Auth) {

        var vm = this;


        // initialization

        vm.users = [];
        vm.selected_convo = undefined;
        vm.selected_user = undefined;
        vm.user_map = {};

        Auth.getLoggedInUser()
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.selected_user = data.user;
            });

    }]);
```

In the Node.js server:

```
// routes/auth.js

...

app.get('/loggedInUser', function(req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        res.status(200).json({
            user: req.user
        });
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'No user is logged in.'
        });
    };
});

...
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @AwakeningByte Good point. **Firefox**. Editing question to include that.

Comment: Try old technique: `var resp = $http.get('/loggedInUser?' + Math.random() );`

Comment: That worked! But do you know why it was not working without that?

Comment: As a clue for those reading this, it happened for me for two API calls: '/loggedInUser' and '/logout'. Those are my only two API calls which take no arguments (not in params nor in body, they are simply a GET request to a path and no other details).